# Records process. - calls on information in .txt file. Python

Tags: python

Help needed with my sale record. my program calls on the information in my text file .
this code below:

```
text_file = open("data.txt", "r")

lines = text_file.readlines()

print (lines)

print (lines)

text_file.close()
```

opens my data.txt file which contains the following information:

```
1-2-2014,Frankton,42305.67,23
12-4-2014,Glenview,21922.22,17
10-2-2015,Glenview,63277.9,32
10-5-2015,Glenview,83290.09,16
11-6-2015,Frankton,81301.82,34
10-10-2015,Frankton,62333.3,40
11-11-2015,Frankton,28998.8,29
1-1-2016,Glenview,51083.5,27
1-3-2016,Glenview,62155.72,42
27-3-2016,Frankton,33075.1,18
2-4-2016,Glenview,61824.7,35
```

how do i write a non-value-returning function print_all_records(records). Where the function takes a list as perimeter and displays the records, one record per line. under different headings.

example in reference to the data.txt file. it should show up like this when printed. with each line containing the information in the text file.

```
Date          Branch             Daily Sale         Transactions
01/02/2014    Frankton           $42305.67          23
12/04/2014    Glenview           $219.22.22         17
```

Comment: Check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable. It's not exactly the format you want but it's very easy to use and also very nice looking.

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment?

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored each line as a string in a list, you can use:

```
def print_all_records(records):
    print("Date" + "\t\t" + "Branch" + "\t\t" + "Daily Sale" + "\t\t" + "Transactions")
    for record in records:
        parts = record.split(",")
        print(parts[0] + "\t" + parts[1] + "\t" + "$" + parts[2] + "\t\t" + parts[3])
```

You can obviously adjust the number of tabs (`\t`) to your own liking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', header = None)

df.columns = ['Date', 'Branch', 'Daily Sale', 'Transactions']

print(df.to_string(index = False, justify = 'left'))
```

Output -

```
Date        Branch     Daily Sale  Transactions
   1-2-2014  Frankton  42305.67    23          
  12-4-2014  Glenview  21922.22    17          
  10-2-2015  Glenview  63277.90    32          
  10-5-2015  Glenview  83290.09    16          
  11-6-2015  Frankton  81301.82    34          
 10-10-2015  Frankton  62333.30    40          
 11-11-2015  Frankton  28998.80    29          
   1-1-2016  Glenview  51083.50    27          
   1-3-2016  Glenview  62155.72    42          
  27-3-2016  Frankton  33075.10    18          
   2-4-2016  Glenview  61824.70    35
```

Comment: thanks. importerror: no moduel named pandas

Comment: Pandas is an external module. You gotta install it.

Comment: oh thank you. i was also wondering is there a way for my program to search through the data.txt file ? for example if you input a date that matches a date in the data.txt file it prints out its information . (I would probably need to start a new thread wouldnt i ? )

Comment: i did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373260/search-a-data-txt-file-for-information-based-on-user-input-python-3-5-1#