# Search a data.txt file for information based on user input and print it(Python 3.5.1)

Tags: python

the code below reads the data.txt file and prints the records in the data.txt file.

```
text_file = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
print (lines)
print (lines)
text_file.close()


def print_all_records(records):
print("Date" + "\t\t" + "Branch" + "\t\t" + "Daily Sale" + "\t\t" + "Transactions")
for record in records:
    parts = record.split(",")
    print(parts[0] + "\t" + parts[1] + "\t" + "$" + parts[2] + "\t\t" + parts[3])
```

example of information in the data.txt file

```
1-2-2014,Frankton,42305.67,23
12-4-2014,Glenview,21922.22,17
10-2-2015,Glenview,63277.9,32
```

how do i make it so that i can query the records by date. for example if a user input the date 1 2 2014 it would search the data.txt file to find if that date exists then print that line of the record. and if it doesnt find anything it asks the user try again and again until it finds a date that matches a record.

Comment: By adding the code for that - lots more. By the way, your shown code has indentation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you use Python 3.

```
def print_entries(date):
    """Prints all the entries that match with date"""
    with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
        flag = False
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [line.strip('\n').split(',') for line in content]
        for row in content:
            if row[0] == date:
                flag = True
                print(*row, sep='\t')
        if not flag:
            print('Try again')
        return flag


while not print_entries(input("Enter date :")):
    pass
```

If you're using Python 2, replace `print(*row, sep = '\t')` with `print('\t'.join(row))`.

Running the program -

```
Enter date :12-4-2014
12-4-2014   Glenview    21922.22    17
```

Comment: thats perfect thanks. i was just wondering for this code if the user input a date that was not on the record is it possible to display a message then prompt them to try again ? would i be using an else statement for that ? and also how do i remove the " - " in between the date so that it will accept the date without them

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, it would be nice to set the answer as 'accepted' :)

Comment: Your dates are quite messy. They're not in dd-mm-yyyy format. 12-4-2014 should rather be 12-04-2014, otherwise it would be confusing to read them without '-' in between.

Comment: If you want to prompt the user to try again, just add a `flag` variable with initial value as `False`. If a match is found then set it to `True`. Outside the `for` loop, if `flag` is still `False`, then prompt the user to try again.

Comment: It's just the matter of practice. I can update my code to do the desired thing.

Comment: one last thing i should have mentioned i added more information to data.txt file and input the dates but it is not picking them up..
1-2-2014,Frankton,42305.67,23
12-4-2014,Glenview,21922.22,17
10-2-2015,Glenview,63277.9,32
10-5-2015,Glenview,83290.09,16
11-6-2015,Frankton,81301.82,34
10-10-2015,Frankton,62333.3,40
11-11-2015,Frankton,28998.8,29
1-1-2016,Glenview,51083.5,27
1-3-2016,Glenview,62155.72,42
27-3-2016,Frankton,33075.1,18
2-4-2016,Glenview,61824.7,35

Comment: Anyway, I've updated my code to support 'try again'. I believe your CSV file is not properly formatted, otherwise the code would've worked.

Comment: thanks. on return flag i get the error 'return' outside function

Comment: Fixed it. There was an indentation issue.

Comment: is there a way to add two of the $ together ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382244/add-costs-of-two-dates-together-from-txt-file-and-print-result-python