# Add costs of two dates together from .txt file and print result. python

Tags: python

The program loads info from data.txt file and prints it. How would I go about getting users to input two two dates: (enter start day) a start and (enter end date) and calculate the total $ and print it.

```
searchfile = open("data.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
if "searchphrase" in line: print (line)

searchfile.close()
```

For example if they enter 1.2.2014 as start date
and enter 12.4.2014 as end date it calculates the $ and adds both from the dates and prints the total.

```
1-2-2014,location,$42305.67,23
12-4-2014,location,$21922.22,17
10-2-2015,location,$63277.9,32
10-5-2015,location,$83290.09,16
```

Comment: Please check your indentation. This code is just going to open a file and error out. Also, you have described what you want the program to do. Is there any way to put this into code? Maybe start by asking for two inputs, storing them into two variables...

Comment: It's unclear what output you want. In the example you show do you want   `64227.89` as output?

Comment: for example if the user enters the start and end date i want the function to iterate through my record (the text file) and calculate the $ between the 2 dates. so for example if start date is 1.2.2014 and end date is 10.2.2015 then it adds the $ of the dates from the start date though to the end date and prints an output . (if its still unclear i can try explain again.)